# Monitor does not come out of sleep at power-up until I press reset button

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, graphics-card, pip, virtualenv

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.1 to Ubuntu 19.04. My PC configuration is:

- **Motherboard:** Gigabyte EP43T-USB3
- **Processor:** Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q8400 @ 2.66GHz
- **Graphics:** Nvidia GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2 (2GB RAM)
- **RAM:** 16 GB
- **HARD DISK:** 128 SSD
- **EXTERNAL HARDDISK:** 2TB Transcend
- **OS:** Ubuntu 19.04 (64-bit)

I am learning full stack web development using Python based Django framework. For the need of latest software I have upgrade from my Linux Ubuntu 18.1 to 19.4 version for using the upgraded version of Python and PostgreSQL.

After upgrading, the system was working very well. No black screen no hang. I installed PostgreSQL 11 and PgAdmin4 for PostgreSQL. I installed Pip3 and Virtualenv. I also installed VLC that took a very long... time to install. Besides, Visual Studio Code, Atom, Google Chrome, Opera and Virtualbox also have been installed after upgrading.

Moreover, I installed proprietary Nvidia Graphics Card driver 390 (recommended) by using the GUI Additional Drivers' option. It has worked well for sometime, and suddenly I discovered that it's not behaving correctly. When I press power button on the CPU runs but there is nothing on the monitor and it remains black; and I wait some moments. Then when I press reset button it starts.

I am not a technical expert, and I'm also new on Linux. That's why it becomes my nightmare. I spent my whole day and night to solve it but found no ways.

Could you guys please help me to solve the problem that will make my life normal? That will make me smile again! Thanks in again!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Quick sanity check: have you got the PWR and RESET buttons wired correctly? It's possible to have these accidentally switched. (ask me how I know this)

Comment: It seems like the PC turns on from the power button, but the boot doesn't proceed until the reset button is pressed?

Comment: Rename your question. Your question should be "Monitor does not come out of sleep at power-up (new Graphics Card)"

Comment: @bertieb Cordial thanks for your reply, and sorry for late response as I was sleeping for such a hard labor. Before using Ubuntu I8.10 I used Windows 10 64bit on this PC and everything was perfect for those several years. Even when I started using Ubuntu it was last April 2019. From that day to the last 22th June, 2019 everything was fine. Switching buttons were perfect. I didn't rewire them. But now I am curious after you suspect. Can you please tell me how I know this accidental switched? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @vlumi Thanks a lot for replying and sorry for late response. You are right. PC turns on with power button but the boot doesn't proceed until the reset button is pressed. Pretty weird, hun? What is the possible solution dude? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One possibility is that the power supply can't keep up with the cold boot, but can handle it when everything is already running. Or some other power issue. Or CMOS battery getting bad.

Comment: @vlumi - Power supply would be very expensive to change this time for me. But I will replace the battery with a new one. Thanks for your possible solution.

Comment: @vlumi - I changed the CMOS battery and continuously check to see the result, nearly a shift has been spent. But it did not work. What ever, this morning I found my computer is running well. Thanks to everyone for your great and valuable time. Have a good day!